# It does not show result after Ajax post request

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am writing an app. I made asynchronous AJAX reuqest so when you want to go to chat it does not refresh the page. But it does not shows messages, because when I go to network tab and then to response tab of that request all is good- it shows messages.

My HTML code:

```
<form action="apka.php" method="post" class="sendData">
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $rc->picture;?>" class="picture" name="picture" hidden>
    <input type="text" name="chat" class="chat" hidden>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $rc->username;?>" class="username" name="name" hidden>
    <button type="submit" style="background-color:transparent;border:none;color:white"><?php echo $rc->username;?></button>
 </form>
```

My JavaScript code:

```
 <script>

       $('form.sendData').on('submit', function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
        var that = $(this),
            url = that.attr('action'),
            method= that.attr('method'),
            data = {};
            that.find('[name]').each(function() {
                var that = $(this),
                    name= that.attr('name'),
                    value = that.val();
                data[name]=value;
            });
            console.log(data);
          $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: method,
            data: data,
            success: function() {
                $('.card-footer').show();
                $('#messages').show();
                if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
                    $('#chats').hide();
                    $('#friends').hide();
                    $('#add').hide();
                    $('.navbar').hide();
                    $('#back').show();
                    $('#messages').show();
                    $('#show-search').hide();
                    $('#divChat').hide();
                }
            }
          });                     


       });




    </script>
```

And first lines of selecting messages:

```
 <?php

    http_response_code(200);


      require_once "connect.php";
        $connection = new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

            if($connection->connect_errno!=0){
                 echo "Error: " . $connection->connect_errno;
            }else{
              $picture=$_POST['picture'];
              $name=$_POST['name'];
              $username=$_SESSION['username'];
              $username_messages = $username.'messages';
              $result_messages=$connection->query("SELECT * FROM $username_messages WHERE nameUser='$username' AND nameFriend='$name' OR nameUser='$name' AND nameFriend='$username'");
              $how_much_messages = $result_messages->num_rows;
                ?>
```

Here you can see response
[image: Response]

I put response here:

```
<div class="card">
   <div class="card-header msg_head">
     <div class="d-flex bd-highlight">
        <div class="img_cont">
           <img src="https://cdmessenger.pl/profiles/<?php if(isset($picture)) echo $picture;?>" class="rounded-circle user_img" id="photo-message">
           <span class="online_icon"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="user_info">
           <span id="username-message"><?php if(isset($name)) echo $name;?></span>
           <p><?php echo $how_much_messages;?> wiadomości</p>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Then I check if isset session variable which contains error when there are 0 messages. If not i put this:

```
while($rm=$result_messages->fetch_object()) {
    if($rm->nameUser==$username) {
      ?>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end mb-4 messages">
       <div class="msg_cotainer_send">
          <?php echo base64_decode($rm->messages);?>
          <span class="msg_time"><?php echo $rm->datas;?></span>
       </div>
    <div class="img_cont_msg">
      <img src="https://cdmessenger.pl/profiles/<?php echo $rm->picture;?>" class="rounded-circle user_img_msg">
     </div>
   </div>

   <?php
     } elseif($rm->nameUser!=$_SESSION['username']) {
       ?>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-start mb-4 messages">
        <div class="img_cont_msg">
        <img src="https://cdmessenger.pl/profiles/<?php echo $rm->picture;?>" class="rounded-circle user_img_msg">
         </div>
        <div class="msg_cotainer">
          <?php echo base64_decode($rm->messages);?>
          <span class="msg_time"><?php echo $rm->datas;?></span>
       </div>
     </div>
    <?php
      }
     }
    ?>
  </div>
```

Comment: are you sending any response from your php?

Comment: r u showing this response in any div? something like `$("#your indicater").html(your response);` ??? your question is unclear.

Comment: @devpro I edited post

Answer (score 0):

You need to update some div with the ajax return:

```
$.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: method,
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                $('.card-footer').show();
                $('#messages').show();
                if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
                    $('#chats').hide();
                    $('#friends').hide();
                    $('#add').hide();
                    $('.navbar').hide();
                    $('#back').show();
                    $('#messages').show();
                    $('#show-search').hide();
                    $('#divChat').hide();

                    $('#someDiv').innerHTML = data;
                }
            }
          });
```

Comment: Because you need to have an element with id "someDiv" in your DOM

Comment: With your update, I guess it should be displayed in $('#username-message)

Comment: It shows "[object Object]" where $username-message now

Comment: Can you show the result of a console.log of data, please?

Comment: {picture: "38933038_924349597744760_2247235715148546048_o.jpg", chat: "", name: "crazyadmin09"} for example

Comment: Then you can access "picture", "chat" and "name" by using `$('#someDiv').innerHTML = data.picture;`
`$('#someDiv').innerHTML = data.chat;`
`$('#someDiv').innerHTML = data.name;`

Comment: Okey thanks it works, but i don't know why php doesn't catch it to post variable and doesn't do select query from database... As you have seen it shows messages in response tab, but in body not